# docker stack rm followed by deploy fails and runs on consecutive builds

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-stack

**Bash script in Jenkins build sections**

```
#!/bin/sh

docker build -t smstake:latest .

#Push to the private  repository applying the proper tags for the image
docker tag smstake:latest reg01.dev.01cloud.com:5000/smstake:1.0.1
docker push reg01.dev.01cloud.com:5000/smstake:1.0.1

docker stack rm smstake
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml smstake
```

1. Here I am creating an docker image
2. Adding the proper tags to it to push to private repository
3. Removing the stack if it exists than deploying it again.

The problem is it fails in the first build with some networks issues which is posted bellow. If build again than it will run successfully on another build. How can I fix this issue.

**Errors I get:**

```
Removing service smstake_app
Removing service smstake_db
Removing service smstake_phpmyadmin
Removing network smstake_smstake
Creating service smstake_app
failed to create service smstake_app: Error response from daemon: network smstake_smstake not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

> As we can see its removing the service and during the service creation
>   its throwing network not found issues.

**Here is my docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  smstake: 
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.10.0/24


services:

    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        networks:
          - smstake
        ports:
          - "3306"
        env_file:
          - configuration.env
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
          MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
          MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
          - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
        deploy:
          mode: replicated
          replicas: 1

    app:

        image: smstake:latest
        ports:
          - 8000:80
        networks:
          - smstake

        depends_on:
          - db
        deploy:
          mode: replicated
          replicas: 1
          placement:
            constraints:
              - node.role == manager

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        networks:
          - smstake
        depends_on:
          - db
        environment:
          PMA_HOST: db
          PMA_PORT: 3306
          MYSQL_USER: *****
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: *****
        ports:
          - '8082:80'
        deploy:
          mode: replicated
          replicas: 1

volumes:
    mysql_data:
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the network is not removed right away in the `docker stack rm smstake` but after this command starts `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml smstake`.

You could wait for the network to be really removed and then deploy the stack again, like this:

```
docker stack rm smstake
while [ $(docker network ls | grep smstake_smstake |  wc -c) -ne 0 ] ; do sleep 1 ; done
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml smstake
```

The `while` is executing as long as the network `smstake_smstake` still exists.

Comment: It's getting stuck `Removing service smstake_app
Removing service smstake_db
Removing service smstake_phpmyadmin
Removing network smstake_smstake
Failed to remove network v4o7gv5ayb1m0tyaokz7hmy8u: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = network v4o7gv5ayb1m0tyaokz7hmy8u is in use by task z3azhlixlxy99khaj3vxue97pFailed to remove some resources from stack: smstake` in here not getting to deploy section

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung You should try to remove the task at the beginning of the file, before anything

Comment: added that on the top of the bash script before any other task but looks like its not going to end. Here is how it is like in jenkins builds section https://pastebin.com/wNH01iVR

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung and the out what it is?

Comment: it gets  stuck sleeping forever. I have found a simple solution just checking to see if it successfully run or not. And than running the deploy command . Now its working great. BUT the problem is though `docker service ls` is showing it running I have to wait few  seconds (20-30sec)for it to come up and running don't know why. 
Here is the changes code. https://pastebin.com/2rTh13i9 .

Comment: Also you can use `wc` command as `wc -l` (counting the line instead the chars).